# First Order differential equations mixing problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone please help me out with the below question? I can't figure it out.

Initially $5$ grams of salt are dissolved into $20$ liters of water. Brine with concentration of salt $5$ grams per liter is added at a rate of $4$ liters per minute. The tank is well mixed and drained at $4$ liters per minute.

Let $x$ be the amount of salt, in grams, in the solution after $t$ minutes have elapsed. Find a formula for the rate of change in the amount of salt, $\frac{dx}{dt}$, in terms of the amount of salt in the solution $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the rate of water coming in and draining out is the same ($4$ liter per minute) so the volume of water remains constant at $20$ liter. Only the amount of salt changes in the water.

Initial salt $= 5$ grams

**Rate of addition = $5 \times 4 = 20$ grams per minute.**

Amount of salt in $20 $ liter of solution after a given time $t$ minutes is $x$ grams.

**So, rate of reduction of salt (drain out) $= 4 \times \frac{x}{20} = \frac{x}{5} \,$ grams per minute**

After time $dt$ from the time $t$ when there is $x$ grams of salt in solution,

$x + dx = x + (20 - \frac{x}{5})dt \,$ (where $dx$ is the amount of salt added in $dt$).

$\frac{dx}{dt} = 20 - \frac{x}{5}$ grams per minute